# php include path issues

Tags: php, path, include

I've read about 100 articles about include path problems, but something just isn't clicking for me. I'm using windows and XAMPP.

My current `include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR"`

Now the file i'm trying to use is located here: `C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\dbgetters\someFunctions.php`

and it needs an include from: `C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\config\Common.php`

So I thought that using this in someFunctions.php would work:
`include '../config/Common.php';`

but it doesn't.

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked your open_basedir directive in php.ini? maybe it is limited to a certain folder? That way you can't include any files from outside of that folder.

Comment: If you execute `someFunction.php` directly, then `../` would refer to  `\dbgetters`, but if your script is being called by, say, `\mywebsite\index.php`, then `.` refers to `\mywebsite`; that is, not the directory of the calling file but of the executed file. Have you checked for that?

Comment: Replace the forward slash `/` with a backward slash `\` and echo `dirname(__FILE__)` right before the include to see exactly where you are.